# Can't instantiate abstract class IEXStockFetcher with abstract methods fetchImageURL, fetchPrice, fetchStockHighLow

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to get this awesome code I found on Github to compile https://github.com/apryor6/stockstreamer/blob/master/data_fetcher.py

I made a few modifications to the code as API URL for IEX has changed this code was published

```
Class IEXStockFetcher(StockFetcher):

    """
    Fetches stock information using iextrading.com API
    """
    url_prefix = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?token=MY TOKEN"

    url_suffix_price = "&price"
    url_suffix_img = "&logo"
    url_suffix_highlow = "&quote"***


When I step through the code and get to the end I receive the following error: "Can't instantiate abstract class IEXStockFetcher with abstract methods fetchImageURL, fetchPrice, fetchStockHighLow"

I am relatively new to object oriented programing in Python. Anyone has any thoughts?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class IEXStockFetcher(StockFetcher):`

```
"""
Fetches stock information using iextrading.com API
"""

url_prefix = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/"
url_suffix_price = "/quote/latestPrice"
url_suffix_img = "/logo"
url_suffix_highlow = "/quote"
url_suffix_token = "?token=pk_44de71531a5d400bb1bd98a2c7dd011d"
```

....
....

`def fetchPrice(self, stock):`

```
    # get the price of a single stock

    try:

        resp = urlopen("{}{}{}{}".format(IEXStockFetcher.url_prefix, stock, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_price, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_token))
        resp = json.loads(resp.readlines()[0].decode('utf8'))
        price = float(resp)
        return price
    except:
        return self.fetchPrice(stock)


def fetchImageURL(self, stock):
    # get the image url of a single stock
    try:
        resp = urlopen("{}{}{}{}".format(IEXStockFetcher.url_prefix, stock, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_img, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_token))
        resp = json.loads(resp.readlines()[0].decode('utf8'))
        return resp['url']
    except:
        return self.fetchImageURL(stock)

def fetchStockHighLow(self, stock):
    # get the image url of a single stock
    try:
        resp = urlopen("{}{}{}{}".format(IEXStockFetcher.url_prefix, stock, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_highlow, IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_token))
        resp = json.loads(resp.readlines()[0].decode('utf8'))
        return (resp['week52High'], resp['week52Low'])
    except:
        return self.fetchStockHighLow(stock)
```

Comment: This solution was used with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code working with the new API.. I had to make a few small modifications

`class IEXStockFetcher(StockFetcher):
    """
    Fetches stock information using iextrading.com API
    """
    url_prefix = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?token=<MY TOKEN>&symbols="
    url_suffix_price = "&types=price"
    url_suffix_img = "&types=logo"
    url_suffix_highlow = "&types=quote"
....
....
....
....`

`def fetchPrice(self, stock):
        # get the price of a single stock
        try:
            resp = urlopen("{}{}{}".format(IEXStockFetcher.url_prefix,stock,IEXStockFetcher.url_suffix_price))
            resp = json.loads(resp.readlines()[0].decode('utf8'))
            price = float(resp[stock]['price'])
            return price
        except:
            return self.fetchPrice(stock)`

Comment: Above solution worked on the Mac but did not work on Ubuntu on Azure.